# If $X$ is the sum of 100 six sided dice, what does Chebychev's inequality say about $P(X < 300)$?

Tags: probability, random-variables

If $X$ is the sum of 100 six sided dice, what does Chebychev's inequality say about $P(X < 300)$?

We can write $X = X_1 + \cdots + X_{100}$ where $X_i$ is the result of the $i$th dice. So far, I know that $EX = 100 \cdot 3.5 = 350$, and so $P(|X - 350| \geq k) \leq \operatorname{Var}(X)/k^2$. How do I use this to get a statement about $P(X < 300)$?

Also, I know that $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{Cov}(X,X)$, but calculating the right hand sides requires calculating $E(X_iX_j)$ for some $i \neq j$, for example $E(X_1X_2)$. Is there a shortcut to calculate this besides the "brute force" method of calculating from definition, ie 
$$E(X_1X_2) = \sum_{i = 1}^6\sum_{j = 1}^6 ij\cdot p(i,j) = \frac{1}{36}\sum_{i = 1}^6\sum_{j = 1}^6 ij$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: Note that $P(X < 300) \le P(X < 300 \ \text{OR} \ X > 400) = P(|X-350| > 50)$.

Also, if you use symmetry to show that $P(X < 300) = P(X > 400)$, then you can say that $P(X < 300) = \dfrac{1}{2}\left[P(X < 300)+P(X > 400)\right] = \dfrac{1}{2}P(X < 300 \ \text{OR} \ X > 400)$, which will give you a stronger bound.

Finally, in regards to computing the variance, remember that the variance of a sum of independent random variables is equal to the sum of the variances of those random variables, i.e. $\displaystyle \text{var}\left(\sum_{i = 1}^{100}X_i\right) = \sum_{i = 1}^{100}\text{var}(X_i)$